# javascript セレクトのオプションのリンク先

Tags: javascript, jquery

セレクトボックスのオプションをクリックするだけでリンクしたいのですが、どれを選択しても最初の値、最初のオプションが選ばれたことになってしまいます。
コードは以下の通りです。

Ｊａｖａｓｃｒｉｐｔ

```
$(".custom-select").each(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class"),
      id      = $(this).attr("id"),
      name    = $(this).attr("name");
  var template =  '<div class="' + classes + '">';
      template += '<span class="custom-select-trigger">' + $(this).attr("placeholder") + '</span>';
      template += '<div class="custom-options">';
      $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        template += '<span class="custom-option ' + $(this).attr("class") + '" data-value="' + $(this).attr("value") + '">' + $(this).html() + '</span>';
      });
  template += '</div></div>';

  $(this).wrap('<div class="custom-select-wrapper"></div>');
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).after(template);
});
$(".custom-option:first-of-type").hover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").addClass("option-hover");
}, function() {
  $(this).parents(".custom-options").removeClass("option-hover");
});
$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $('html').one('click',function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
    var browser = document.selecton.sources.value;
    location.href = browser
}
```

追記
失礼しました。

ＨＴＭＬ

```
<form name="selecton" class="center">
  <select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources">

    <option value="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.co.jp/">google</option>
    <option value="hashtag">Rus-Jap</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: HTMLも含めた、動作可能な完全なコードを掲載してください。とりあえず、document.selecton.sources.value が何なのか現在掲載されているコードからはさっぱりわかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クリックイベントで値を取るなら

```
    $('[name=sources]').on('click',function() {
        var data = $('[name=sources]').val();
        console.log(data);
    });
```

で取れるとおもいます。selectタグでclickイベントは色々忙しいのでchangeで書いてみました。

```js
$(function() {
$('[name=sources]').on('change',function() {
                var data = $('[name=sources]').val();
                alert(data);
            });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="selecton" class="center">
  <select name="sources" id="sources" class="custom-select sources">

    <option value="https://www.yahoo.co.jp/">Yahoo</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.co.jp/">google</option>
    <option value="hashtag">Rus-Jap</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。回答いただいたコード単体では任意のvalueを取得しているんですが、最初に出したコードに組み込むことができません。$(".custom-option").on("click", function() {
    var browser = document.selecton.sources.value;
    location.href = browser
}

Comment: ”セレクトボックスのオプションをクリックするだけでリンク”の意味を誤ってしまいました。
クラス custom-optionの要素をクリックしたら飛べ良いのですね。アトリビュート　data-value　にoptionタグのvalue値がセットされているので$(this).attr('data-value')で値が取れます。
$(".custom-option").on("click", function(){location.href = $(this).attr('data-value');});

Comment: アトリビュートがdata-* でセットされているので　data-value　は　$(this).data("value");});　も取れます。